# iosSlider start/stop button JQuery update

Tags: jquery, ios, slider, carousel

I'm using [iosSlider](https://github.com/iosscripts/iosSlider) and it has settings and options that include autoSlide:true which are set on document ready.

It also has a public method $('div').iosSlider('update'); Which:

> Updates/reinitializes internal variables/CSS attributes based on
>   changes to the HTML/CSS/JS structure of the slider.

So my script for a button div is

```
$("#menuItem1").click(function () {
    $('.iosSlider').iosSlider('goToSlide', 1);
    $('.iosSlider').iosSlider('update');
});
```

and I have no idea where to put autoSlide:false as my update? The slide change works, I just want to stop auto scroll when user jumps to a slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the autoSlideToggleSelector setting which kind of works, I think I'll just have to make two buttons and set if statements (i.e. start button: if sliding, do nothing; stop button: if sliding, stop slider)

Any help still appreciated.

> autoSlideToggleSelector: (string) A jQuery selection (ex.
>   $('#autoScrollToggle') ), the element returned by the selector will
>   disable/enable automatic scrolling when clicked. Note: Only works when
>   autoSlide is set to 'true'.